# Pygame Game Development shoot functionality

Tags: python, pygame

My question is how can I better my shooting functionality in my game. I am trying to make it to where the player can shoot in the direction it is moving (ex.shoot up,down,left,right) as well as shoot while moving and shoot while idle.

The player and missile are both rectangular using pygame shapes to make it easier for me to understand the logic behind game development.

```
def player(px,py):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameWindow,black,[px,py,30,30])

def missile(mx,my):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameWindow,black,[mx,my,10,10])
```

Here is the code of the game to help better understand what I'm talking about. The small section I have commented out is what I have tried. I only have it currently set to move in the x direction going left from its initial starting point.

```
import pygame #####IMPORTING PYGAME MODULE###########################

pygame.init() #####INITIALIZING PYGAME##################################

gameWindow = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600)) ###Screen Width and Height###

clock = pygame.time.Clock() ## FRAMES PER SECOND ##

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0) 


def player(px,py):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameWindow,black,[px,py,30,30])

def missile(mx,my):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameWindow,black,[mx,my,10,10])

def enemies():
    return


def gameloop():
    px = 700
    py = 300

    mx = 700
    my = 300

    px_change = 0
    py_change = 0

    mx_change = 0
    my_change = 0

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    mx_change = -10
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    mx_change = 10
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    my_change = -10
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    my_change = 10

                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE: 
                    mx_change = -6
                #if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    #mx_change = 6


                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    px_change = -10
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    px_change = 10
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    py_change = -10
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    py_change = 10

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    px_change = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    py_change = 0

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    mx_change = 0
                    mx = px
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    my_change = 0
                    my = py
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    mx_change = 0
                    my_change = 0
                    mx = px
                    my = py


        px += px_change
        py += py_change

        mx += mx_change
        my += my_change

        gameWindow.fill(white)

        player(px,py)
        missile(mx,my)
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(100)

    pygame.quit()
    quit()
gameloop()
```

Comment: I don't know why you change missile position using keys. it should change position on its own - move in selected direction all time.

Comment: you could use `pygame.Rect()` to keep player and missile positions ans sizes. Rect() can be used to `draw(..., missille_rect)` and `blit(..., missille_rect)` and it has function to check collisions `player_rect.colliderect(missille_rect)`

Comment: added entire code for better understanding of question.

Comment: when you KEYDOWN SPACE then you should create missile and set its direction and not change it with othe keys. And don't reset it when you KEYUP SPACE. You should kill/remove/reset it after some time or few frame so it will not depends on player positon.

Comment: I think you should read some articles/tuts about really basic game architecture. Your code makes no sense, from my point of view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using different objects for your player and missile.  The way you have things set up right now, there can only be 1 player and 1 missile.  Only having 1 player might be fine but 1 missile makes for a dull game.  I suggest using a class, such as this simple example:

```
class Projectile():
    def init(self,x,y,vx,vy):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.vx = vx
        self.vy = vy
    def update(self): 
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y += self.vy
```

Now that you have a class you can start doing great things! Want to have spacebar fire a new missile instead of moving the one missile on screen? ezpz! All you need is a list of your missile objects to keep track of, say `my_missile_list`:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE: 
      my_missile_list.append(Projectile(px,py,missile_x_velocity,missile_y_velocity))
```

This creates an entirely new instance of the class Projectile based on the input position and speeds.

Finally, we need to have all these missiles move! This is where the class definition makes our life easier! Once per frame we just have to update the bullets:

```
for b in my_missile_list: 
    b.update()
```

There are more advantages to using classes here but this is a start.  If you read through this and make a few changes your game will work much more like what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the help Hoog. I need to read more up on classes to understand the use for them better in game development. Any recommendations?

Comment: I don't know about resources specific to game development, but the official documentatio on Python classes is here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html  Outside of that I suggest practice, once you get the hang of classes using them will be second nature.  Any time you want multiple copies of some object (projectiles, walls, enemies) a class will be a good way to hold all the information you need for those objects.

Answer (score 1):

You should set missille only when you KEYDOWN space, and not use other keys to change it. Player may have variable `direction` so you will know in which direction it is looking when it stay and you will know in which direction move misille.

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
RED   = (255,0,0) 

# --- classes --- (CamelCaseNames)

# empty

# --- functions ---- (lower_case_names_

def player(screen, x, y):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (x, y, 30, 30))

def missile(screen, x, y):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (x, y, 10, 10))

def enemies():
    pass

def gameloop(screen):
    px = 700
    py = 300

    mx = 700
    my = 300

    px_change = 0
    py_change = 0
    p_direction = 'left'

    mx_change = 0
    my_change = 0
    #m_direction = 'left'

    game_exit = False
    clock = pygame.time.Clock() ## FRAMES PER SECOND ##

    while not game_exit:

        # --- events ---

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_exit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    px_change = -10
                    p_direction = 'left'
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    px_change = 10
                    p_direction = 'right'
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    py_change = -10
                    p_direction = 'top'
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    py_change = 10
                    p_direction = 'down'

                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    mx = px
                    my = py
                    if p_direction == 'left':
                        mx_change = -16
                        my_change = 0
                    elif p_direction == 'right':
                        mx_change = 16
                        my_change = 0
                    elif p_direction == 'top':
                        mx_change = 0
                        my_change = -16
                    elif p_direction == 'down':
                        mx_change = 0
                        my_change = 16

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    px_change = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    py_change = 0

        # --- changes/updates ---

        px += px_change
        py += py_change

        mx += mx_change
        my += my_change

        # --- draws ----

        screen.fill(WHITE)

        player(screen, px, py)
        missile(screen, mx, my)
        pygame.display.update()

        # --- FPS ---

        clock.tick(30)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

gameloop(screen)

pygame.quit()
#quit()
```

Instead of `px, py` and `mx,my` you should use `pygame.Rect()` - it can be used to `draw()` and `blit()` and it has methods to check collisions.

Comment: Nice but it doesn't follow the player if you move first before shooting.

Comment: So, for me to get the missile to continue in the direction and shoot multiple missiles I would have to implement classes?

Comment: I didn't know you want to missile following player. I thougth that it should move in own direction and that it is your problem.

Comment: To have many misilles you have to keep them on list. It is easier when every missille is a instance of class or at least a dictionary/list with its parameters. PyGame has class [pygame.sprite.Sprite](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) which has usefull functions - you can keep all sprites in `pygame.sprite.Group()` and check collision with other group and automatically remove "killed" items. You can also use one command to draw all items in group. All this make code shorter.